# Opportunity Validation exclude validation for certain Profile IDs

Tags: validation-rule

I'm trying to validate certain Opportunity records but exclude that validation on certain profiles. The following is the code I currently have but it's not taking the profile.id in to consideration:

```
AND(($RecordType.Id = "0122000000006WO"),
NOT(
OR($User.ProfileId = "00620000003ouWr")),
TEXT(StageName) != "Lead 0%",
ISBLANK(TEXT(Unsolicited_Bid__c)
)
)
```

Do I have the `($User.ProfileId = "00620000003ouWr")` statement in the correct spot for it to exclude validating for this profile Id? Am I doing this correctly?

Thanks for your time in advance!

Answer (score 2):

if your requirement is to check

- Stage is NOT Lead 0% AND
- RecodType is 0122000000006WO AND
- Profile is NOT 00620000003ouWr AND
- if Unsolicited Bid is blank

then you can use this

```
AND(
 $RecordType.Id = "0122000000006WO", 
 $Profile.Id != "00620000003ouWr", 
 TEXT(StageName) != "Lead 0%", 
 ISBLANK(TEXT(Unsolicited_Bid__c) ) 
)
```

if possible try using **RecordType Name** and **Profile Name** instead of Ids so that it becomes easy when you deploy and move this between different environments and its more readable & easy for future maintenance.